# Disabling ARC within a non-official library causing issue to Apple?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

i've downloaded a non-official library and added to my project, but due to the fact it was written before ARC there was to much code to change (all release and so on..) so i simply disabled ARC in that implementation files and everything worked fine.
But was wondering if i submit to apple store, would Apple complain about this, rejecting my app? If yes due to ARC-disable or for the library?

Comment: Doing projects completely without ARC. There is nothing wrong with MRC.

Comment: @Sulthan There's nothing wrong with doing all of an app's UI in code instead of using Interface Builder either. But I like to use all the provided conveniences, myself.

Comment: @Abizern Well, for an experienced developer, MRC or ARC doesn't make much of a difference. The code looks almost the same and using either doesn't save much time. They both have pros and cons. On the other hand, using Interface Builder simplifies code and saves lots of time (even when not using storyboards). I don't think it's a good analogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine - I've done this myself several times. Just turn off arc for the library.

Comment: Cool :) Even for a third-part library Apple won't complain?

Comment: No - in fact it's nearly always only (slightly in need of updating) third party frameworks that need this :D